# Response Timeout Property in CXF

Tags: java, websphere, cxf, websphere-8

We are currently in the process of migrating out of WebSphere to an open source Application server (preferably Tomcat), so as a step 1, I am trying to migrate the code that used Websphere Webservice jars into CXF. I was able to get all the things done except one.

```
com.ibm.wsspi.webservices.Constants.RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_PROPERTY
```

I am just unable to trace anything similar in CXF to this. The only thing remotely close to it is:

```
org.apache.cxf.message.Message.RECEIVE_TIMEOUT
```

There are a few other timeouts available in CXF, just not sure which one to use, as this is the first time dealing with this API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at `HTTPClientPolicy` from Apache CXF

Example:

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(30000L);
http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
```

Read more on the following URL to see other properties (including other types of timeouts): http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/transports/http/configuration/HTTPClientPolicy.html

Comment: In the codem it is being used in this way:
`bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(com.ibm.wsspi.webservices.Constants.RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_PROPERTY, connectTimeout);`

Thanks I will give it a try.

Comment: Although it is not tested, that will take a long time to get it done. But at least the code is compiling fine. I will revisit this later on and give a proper comment.